# Changing the locale doesn't change the decimal separator

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I'd like to use the comma (`,`) instead of the dot (`.`) as decimal separator for `inputText` and `outputText`.

If I add a `f:converterNumber` with `locale="es"` to a inputText, it works:

```
<h:inputText id="myField" value="#{var.field}">
    <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0.000000001" />
    <f:convertNumber locale="es" />
</h:inputText>
```

But I don't want to have to add this tag for every `inputText` and `outputText` in every view I create!

I tried setting "`es_ES`" (spanish from Spain) as default locale in faces-config.xml and the validation messages change to spanish, but the `inputText` still uses the dot as decimal separator.

I also tried wrapping the `h:body` tag with a `<f:view locale="es_ES"></f:view>`, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like this  ?

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
      <default-locale>es_ES</default-locale>
    </locale-config>
</application>
```

Comment: Yes, and the validation messages change to spanish, but the inputText still uses the dot as decimal separator!

Comment: @herreria Which implementation of JSF are you using ?